# Phone number visual transformation in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose, phone-number

How can I implement phone number visual transformation in jetpack compose? I have read this [article](http://zenandroid.io/using-the-jetpack-composes-visualtransformation-to-create-a-credit-card-text-input/) for the card number.

And I want to format my phone number like this `xx xxx xx xx`

Comment: Do you need this transformation while the user types in an `EditTextField`?

Comment: Yes, I want to transform it while the user types.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The dynamic phone number formatter.

[image: The result]

Some examples with different masks.

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen() {
    var phoneNumber by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    Column {
        PhoneField(phoneNumber,
            mask = "000 000 00 00",
            maskNumber = '0',
            onPhoneChanged = { phoneNumber = it })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))

        PhoneField(phoneNumber,
            mask = "(000) 000 00 00",
            maskNumber = '0',
            onPhoneChanged = { phoneNumber = it })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))

        PhoneField(phoneNumber,
            mask = "+7-000-000-00-00",
            maskNumber = '0',
            onPhoneChanged = { phoneNumber = it })
    }
}

@Composable
fun PhoneField(
    phone: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mask: String = "000 000 00 00",
    maskNumber: Char = '0',
    onPhoneChanged: (String) -> Unit
) {
    TextField(
        value = phone,
        onValueChange = { it ->
            onPhoneChanged(it.take(mask.count { it == maskNumber }))
        },
        label = {
            Text(text = "Phone number")
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone),
        visualTransformation = PhoneVisualTransformation(mask, maskNumber),
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
}

class PhoneVisualTransformation(val mask: String, val maskNumber: Char) : VisualTransformation {

    private val maxLength = mask.count { it == maskNumber }

    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        val trimmed = if (text.length > maxLength) text.take(maxLength) else text

        val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
            if (trimmed.isEmpty()) return@buildAnnotatedString

            var maskIndex = 0
            var textIndex = 0
            while (textIndex < trimmed.length && maskIndex < mask.length) {
                if (mask[maskIndex] != maskNumber) {
                    val nextDigitIndex = mask.indexOf(maskNumber, maskIndex)
                    append(mask.substring(maskIndex, nextDigitIndex))
                    maskIndex = nextDigitIndex
                }
                append(trimmed[textIndex++])
                maskIndex++
            }
        }

        return TransformedText(annotatedString, PhoneOffsetMapper(mask, maskNumber))
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other !is PhonedVisualTransformation) return false
        if (mask != other.mask) return false
        if (maskNumber != other.maskNumber) return false
        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return mask.hashCode()
    }
}

private class PhoneOffsetMapper(val mask: String, val numberChar: Char) : OffsetMapping {

    override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
        var noneDigitCount = 0
        var i = 0
        while (i < offset + noneDigitCount) {
            if (mask[i++] != numberChar) noneDigitCount++
        }
        return offset + noneDigitCount
    }

    override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int =
        offset - mask.take(offset).count { it != numberChar }
}
```

Comment: There's an ignorable typo in `PhoneVisualTraformation` usage.
BTW thanks for the detailed solution. Helped me!

Answer (score 8):

You can just modify some params from the example link that you provided according to the pattern you need. You need to consider the max length you want, how many spaces you need between each section.

For example in your given link here: http://zenandroid.io/using-the-jetpack-composes-visualtransformation-to-create-a-credit-card-text-input/

1. They're adding space after every 4th character in  `AnnotatedString.Builder()` You need it on 1, 4, 6.
2. then they've added 2 spaces that's why they're adding spaces like 2,4,6 in  `originalToTransformed` but you need 1,2,3 & same for deducting in `transformedToOriginal`

**Complete code example:**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Test()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun Test() {

    var mobileNumber by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    Column {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 10.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "Mobile number",
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            BasicTextField(
                value = mobileNumber,
                onValueChange = { mobileNumber = it },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
                visualTransformation = { mobileNumberFilter(it) }
            )
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(1.dp)
                .padding(start = 10.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Gray)
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text(text = "Actual value:\n$mobileNumber")
    }

}

const val mask = "xx xxx xx xx"

fun mobileNumberFilter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
    // change the length
    val trimmed =
        if (text.text.length >= 9) text.text.substring(0..8) else text.text

    val annotatedString = AnnotatedString.Builder().run {
        for (i in trimmed.indices) {
            append(trimmed[i])
            if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
                append(" ")
            }
        }
        pushStyle(SpanStyle(color = Color.LightGray))
        append(mask.takeLast(mask.length - length))
        toAnnotatedString()
    }

    val phoneNumberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <= 1) return offset
            if (offset <= 4) return offset + 1
            if (offset <= 6) return offset + 2
            if (offset <= 9) return offset + 3
            return 12
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <= 1) return offset
            if (offset <= 4) return offset - 1
            if (offset <= 6) return offset - 2
            if (offset <= 9) return offset - 3
            return 9
        }
    }

    return TransformedText(annotatedString, phoneNumberOffsetTranslator)
}
```

**Output:**

[image: visual transformation]

Answer (score 2):

For a north American version:

```
const val mask = "(xxx) xxx-xxxx"
fun mobileNumberFilter(text: AnnotatedString, formType: FormType): 
TransformedText {
    if (formType != FormType.SHIPPING_PHONE) {
        return VisualTransformation.None.filter(text)
    }

    // change the length
    val trimmed =
    if (text.text.length >= 14) text.text.substring(0..13) else text.text

    val annotatedString = AnnotatedString.Builder().run {
        for (i in trimmed.indices) {
            val trimmedPortion = trimmed[i]
            if (i == 0) {
               append("($trimmedPortion")
            } else {
               append(trimmedPortion)
            }
            if (i == 2) {
               append(") ")
            }
            if (i == 5) {
               append("-")
            }
        }
        pushStyle(
            SpanStyle(color = Color.LightGray)
        )
        try {
            append(mask.takeLast(mask.length - length))
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            Timber.d(e.localizedMessage?.plus(" reached end of phone number"))
        }

        toAnnotatedString()
    }

    val translator = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {

            if (offset <= 1) return offset
            if (offset <= 4) return offset + 1
            if (offset <= 9) return offset + 2
            return 14

        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {

            if (offset <= 1) return offset
            if (offset <= 4) return offset - 1
            if (offset <= 9) return offset - 2
            return 14

        }
    }

    return TransformedText(annotatedString, translator)
}
```

For an even cleaner version, see this Medium Article:

[Adding Phone Number Visual transformation](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hands-on-jetpack-compose-visualtransformation-to-create-a-phone-number-formatter-99b0347fc4f6)