# Compose VisualTransformation PhoneNumber separate each 3 numbers by space

Tags: android, math, formula, android-jetpack-compose

Am trying to make a visual transformation in `TextField` composable

Example 01111111111 -> 011 111 111 11

Note: I want to append space after each 3 numbers for any length of numbers

I Figured a formula to calculate the offset of original to transformed but I don't can't figure how to reverse that

```
val phoneNumberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
    override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
        return (i % 3) + (4 * (i.div(3)))
    }

    override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
        // I couldn't figure a formula to do that
        return TODO()
    }
}
```

Example outputs of the formula in `originalToTransformed()`

0 -> 0 
1 -> 1 
2 -> 2 
3 -> 4 
4 -> 5 
5 -> 6 
6 -> 8 
7 -> 9 
8 -> 10 
9 -> 12 
10 -> 13

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71325393/3585796) seems what you're looking for

Comment: No it's for a limited number, I want to make it general to any length of numbers

Comment: `i - i.div(4)`?

Comment: How simple is that, that's right, make it an nice answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
    return i - i.div(4)
}
```