# android-jetpack compose-> format text field to display spaces after every 4 characters and move focus after space

Tags: android, request, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, autofocus

I'm trying to implement InputTextField to take credit/debit card number, my requirement is need space after every 4 digit and need to move focus after added space.

InputTextField should print like 1234 56|
(| indicates focus requester)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74526322/7874746

Comment: @AbdullahJaved shared link is helpful. Thank you